# Read the Avro data from Kafka topic using Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, avro

We are having trouble Reading the Avro data from Kafka topic using Apache Nifi.

We tried the ConvertAvrotoJSON processor and we also pasted the Schema also but no luck.

I m getting the below error, AvroRuntimeexception: Malformed data lenght is negative

[image]

Comment: What errors are you getting? What does the schema look like? Can you provide some sample input?

Comment: Are you using Confluent Schema Registry?

Comment: Updated the error screenshot. I m not sure on Confluent Schema Registry

Comment: Please show the definition of your AvroReader and Kafka consumer. Also explain how data is produced to Kafka